# Determine whether the macro/function is in subscript, in superscript, or neither

Tags: xetex, expl3, latex3, xparse

I would like to provide different formatting for an `xparse` command, depending on whether the command is expanded in superscript, in subscript, or neither.

That is, I would like to know inside the command

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\command}{}{%
    % here
}
```

whether it is being invoked like

```
{}^{\command}

{}_{\command}
```

or

```
\command
```

A question like this has already been asked: [Can I detect whether my macro is being used inside a subscript or superscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87939).
I would like to find a direct solution I could later expand upon, provided I'm working with `latex3` and `xetex`, if either is of relevance here.

If there is no direct means provided by the kernel, I believe a comparison with the size of the box (?) in which `\command` is expanded may be a good proxy.

---

Thank to the comments some misconceptions dissipated and I've come up with an approach to "dimension measurement" referred to elsewhere.

In the example provided in the comments, I now have replaced the fixed-height `\big|` strut (`vphantom`) with a strut constructed as follows.

```
\savebox{\testbox}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
% \settodepth{\dimen0}{\testbox}%
\settoheight{\dimen1}{\testbox}%
% \addtolength{\dimen1}{\dimen0}% Not universally appropriate.
\addtolength{\dimen1}{0.375 \dimen1}%
\rule{0pt}{\dimen1}%
```

where `\newsavebox{\testbox}` is invoked outside of the macro.

This, however, does not properly set the height of superscript or subscript arguments, e.g.,

```
$\settoheight{\dimen0}{k}$ \the\dimen0  == ${}^{\settoheight{\dimen0}{k}}$  \the\dimen0
```

are identical.

It is furthermore **still lacking the self-referential property desired**.

Comment: You can't know that by default, but you can now what's the *style* with `\mathchoice{displaystyle}{textstyle}{scripststyle}{scriptscriptstyle}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't really do what you want, because TeX acts in exactly the same way when it's building the math list for a superscript or a subscript; the eventual attribution to the corresponding field is done much later than the level of macro expansion. It's possible that LuaTeX makes this information available, but with pure TeX one can achieve this only by changing the meaning of `^` and `_`. Can you add some motivation for your problem?

Comment: The key to remember with `\mathchoice` is that, while only one style is typeset in the end, all four styles are constructed in boxes, before the right one is selected.  This means that parameters set in a `\mathchoice` are lost upon exiting `\mathchoice`, because they are in essence set 4 times, and the `\scriptscriptstyle` version will be the last one remembered, even if that isn't the one that gets typeset.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks, this goes in the line of the answer by David Carlisle to the referred question. I perceive it as an indirect work-around. But I, certainly, will have to consider it.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your in-depth explanation, this clarifies some misconceptions. As my motivation, consider a macro expanding to `\left| \vphantom{\big|} #1 \right|` which, admittedly, is a quick fix, without properly extending the height in terms of dimensions (if possible). When this command is in a regular-style expression, the result is as desired. In sub- and superscript `\big|` is too high. It was meant to not augment the height if `#1` is higher than `\big|`. Maybe proper dimension measurement would dismiss the issue altogether -- I'd then like to ask for a reference.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thanks! This seems an important point to consider.

Comment: For example, invoking `\def\styledepend{%
  \mathchoice%
  {\gdef\smode{D}\smode}%
  {\gdef\smode{T}\smode}%
  {\gdef\smode{S}\smode}%
  {\gdef\smode{s}\smode}%
  \smode}` will print two letters.  The first `\smode` will be correct because it is printed inside the `\mathchoice`, whereas the second will always be an `s`, because it is the last one remembered upon exiting `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Wow, I guess I would be trying to figure out what would have gone wrong. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @user73358 Aren't you looking for `\mathstrut` or `\vphantom{whatever}`?

Comment: @user73358 So you don't really need to distinguish between subscript and superscripts, but only if the macro is used in a sub/superscript or not.

Comment: @Manuel: I am using `\vphantom` which is unsatisfactory as previously noted in my reply to egreg above. I didn't figure out how to measure the height of the argument and increment the strut's height appropriately.

Comment: @egreg: That's right. I assumed there is a difference between subscript and superscript when typesetting. But, in this particular case, I only need to fix the strut `\vphantom{\big|}` if the macro is invoked in any of subscript or superscript (if there is no difference, then the disjunction is inclusive).

Comment: If your question isn't general, but has a specific function in mind, perhaps you could edit your question to give more details.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: The question is indeed general. It is currently an issue of a few macros, one of which served as an example to clarify my question. But as stated in the question, I would like to expand upon a general solution which would implement some proper proxy for the (logically) exclusive case as stated in the question, or offer a means to determine the dimensions of the box in which the command is expanded (to compare it with the size of subscript and/or superscript).

Comment: `\big` is a fixed size command and doesn't get smaller in subscripts so why you you need this information for the phantom version?

Comment: `\big|` was used as a quick fix for the indended (proper) scaling of the height for `\left| #1 \right|`. In normal-style, it simply increased the height of an argument like `A`, while left the height of `\frac{a}{b}` unaffected. After looking at it, during this comment session, I'm considering to do proper dimension measurement, albeit do not yet know how to procede, since I've never worked with dimensions beyond `\phantom` and simple `\setlength`.

Comment: @user73358 You shouldn't be using `\left` and `\right` to begin with, in my opinion. The output of `\lvert x\rvert` is just good without any need for artificially enlarging the bars.

Comment: If the goal is to scale one object based in some way on the size of another object, you might have a look at my `scalerel` package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thanks, I'll take a look at it tonight.

Comment: @user73358 May be I don't understand but, isn't `\mathstrut` (or `\vphantom(` if you prefer) enough? BTW: you should add a proper example to the question, you have certainly added info in the comments (altough not enough, I think). Better add the full info to the question ;)

Comment: In your follow-up example, `\savebox{\testbox}{\ensuremath{#1}}` will always set the box in `\textstyle`, unless the actual style is specified inside the box (i.e., `\savebox{\testbox}{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle#1}}`).  Thus, you are right back to the need for a `\mathchoice` in order to auto-differentiate the different cases.